# Change in content of one cell changes other cells as well in UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, custom-cell, reuseidentifier

I have created a custom cell and added a uibutton on it. On tap of that button, Im setting that button selected which changes button's image.

```
-(IBAction)btnInfoPressed:(id)sender
{
    [btnInfo setSelected:YES];
}
```

The above method is in the custom cell class. Now when I scroll down, after some cells, some other cell's button is also selected even though I havent tapped that button.

Here is my cellforrowatindexpath method:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";
CustomCell *c = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

if (c == nil)
{
    c = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
}
c.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
return c;
}
```

Any ideas what needs to be done about it?

Comment: Show method `[btnInfo setSelected:YES]`.

Comment: Its the default UIButton property to change its state from Normal to selected or back to normal.

Comment: Then should not you use `[sender setSelected:YES]`?

Comment: It still makes the buttons in other cells selected.

Comment: You cannot use the *cell* to store the "selection state" of a row, because cells are *reused*. You have to store that information for each row in some data source and always set the cells's state in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: Its no the selection of a row. Its the selection state of a UIButton inside a custom cell. On tap of that button all I want is to make that  BUTTON selected and its working fine. But when I scroll down, some other cell's button also shows selected.

Comment: @AmmadHussain: But the reason is the same. The table view allocates only a finite number of cells.  If you scroll down, `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` returns one of the existing cells that have become invisible. Therefore, you have to update the complete state of the cell (including the button's state) in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: @MartinR: You are right. I had to save the state of a cell and all its contents in a data source. Then on every cellforrowatindexpath I have to refresh the contents of cell from that data source. Its working fine now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(From my above comments:)* 
You cannot use the cell to store the state of a row, because cells are reused.
The table view allocates only a finite number of cells. If you scroll down, `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` returns one of the existing cells that have become invisible. Therefore, you have to store the row's state in a data source and
update the complete state of the cell (including the button's state) in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.